# Настройка размера метки на разных зумах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В песочнице яндекса лежит такой пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/scalable_placemarks
Разница в том, что у меня не отдельно создаваемая метка, а коллекция меток. Соответственно, в примере создан layout, который применяется к метке(задает ее ширину, хинт и т.д.), а у моих иконок имеется свой пресет, задающий параметры.
Как переработать пример для коллекции?

Answer (score 1):

Привет, если вы используете ObjectManager тогда вы можете переопределить опцию geoObjectIconLayout и в ней задать шаблон для меток. Вот пример:

```
var createChipsLayout = function (calculateSize, map) {
// Создадим макет метки.
    var Chips = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div class="placemark"></div>',
        {
            build: function () {
                Chips.superclass.build.call(this);
                if (!this.inited) {
                    this.inited = true;
                    // Получим текущий уровень зума.
                    var zoom = map.getZoom();
                    // Подпишемся на событие изменения области просмотра карты.
                    map.events.add('boundschange', function () {
                        // Запустим перестраивание макета при изменении уровня зума.
                        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
                        if (currentZoom != zoom) {
                            zoom = currentZoom;
                            this.rebuild();
                        }
                    }, this);
                }
                var options = this.getData().options,
                    // Получим размер метки в зависимости от уровня зума.
                    size = calculateSize(map.getZoom()),
                    element = this.getParentElement().getElementsByClassName('placemark')[0],
                    // По умолчанию при задании своего HTML макета фигура активной области не задается,
                    // и её нужно задать самостоятельно.
                    // Создадим фигуру активной области "Круг".
                    circleShape = {type: 'Circle', coordinates: [0, 0], radius: size / 2};
                // Зададим высоту и ширину метки.
                element.style.width = element.style.height = size + 'px';
                // Зададим смещение.
                element.style.marginLeft = element.style.marginTop = -size / 2 + 'px';
                // Зададим фигуру активной области.
                options.set('shape', circleShape);
            }
        }
    );

    return Chips;
};

ymaps.ready(function () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.755249, 37.617437],
        zoom: 4
    });

    var placemarks = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [
        {
            type: 'Feature',
          id: 0,
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [55.755249, 36.317437]
          },
          properties: {
            hintContent: 'Метка 1'
          }
        },
        {
            type: 'Feature',
          id: 1,
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [55.755249, 37.617437]
          },
                    properties: {
            hintContent: 'Метка 2'
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    var om = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
    om.add(placemarks.features);
    map.geoObjects.add(om);
    om.options.set("geoObjectIconLayout", createChipsLayout(function (zoom) {
            // Минимальный размер метки будет 8px, а максимальный 200px.
            // Размер метки будет расти с квадратичной зависимостью от уровня зума.
            return Math.min(Math.pow(zoom, 2) + 8, 200);
        }, map)
    );

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/he3fhndf/6/

Comment: Как в созданный layout добавить стандартный default#imageWithContent ?